# p:datatable addRow() added to current page and not allowing paging

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I' trying to use addRow function feature `onclick="PF('dataTableWidgetVar').addRow();"` to add a new row to a *editable* datatable as below. It's inserting a new row but pagination not working and row inserted into current page.

Primefaces 7.0.

```
<p:dataTable widgetVar="dataTableWidgetVar" paginator="true"
                                 paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
                                 paginatorPosition="bottom"
                                 editable="true" editMode="cell"
                                 rows="5"
                                 rowsPerPageTemplate="20,40,60">

// <p:column> ... 

    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton oncomplete="PF('dataTableWidgetVar').addRow()"/>
    </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>
```

Here, 6th new row, added current page and next page not working automatically.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you follow the showcase example exactly? https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/addRow.xhtml. I see in their AddRow they have a actionListener that adds a new row to the backing collection?

Comment: can you post the datasource and bean you use?